# iPhone Camera API and Zoom

Tags: iphone

I am just curious as to how current ZOOM-Camera Apps on the AppStore  are implemented (Are they using undocumented APIs?)

Comment: If they were using undocumented APIs, you wouldn't see them on the AppStore. Apple doesn't permit that.

Answer (score 0):

They're probably just cropping into a section of a photo, and interpolating it bigger. Since there's no hardware zoom in the phone, you have to "fake" it.